# difference between index and meta in search and lucene's support

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene, metadata

Are there any differences between metadata and index in terms of search? m My understanding is that metadata for a document can be something such as author, keyword, etc.  Index operation can be performed against the content body itself, against the metadata itself, against the metadata body+ metadata. Is this understanding right? What kind of support that lucene provide for metadata extraction and indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, from Lucene's perspective, they are all just fields with different names (and types in Solr), but just fields.